# Inkscape Python Extension - getting size of a group

Tags: python, plugins, inkscape

I got a little problem: I define a group in Python with the inkex module of Inkscape for Python:

```
ll1g_attribs = {inkex.addNS('label','inkscape'):'Layout Line 1' } 
ll1g = inkex.etree.SubElement(self.current_layer, 'g', ll1g_attribs)
```

Then I add some vectors to that group, set the transform and place it in Inkscape:

```
tlc = 'translate(' + str( 0 ) + ',' + str( 0 ) + ')' # Top Left Corner
ll1g.set( 'transform',tlc)
```

Is there any way I can get the size of that group I made?
Without any of such function I'd have to analyse the sizes while creating - it's not that easy ;-).